# I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while using the BufferedReader and the .split() method

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

So basically, I'm trying to keep taking input from the user and printing it line by line, until he's done, then I'll print done. Problem is, the code works just fine until I press double Enter/Return, it's supposed to print DONE however it returns an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException @ 1. So what am I doing wrong?

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));   
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] tmp = line.split(" ");
        System.out.println(tmp[0] + " " + tmp[1]);
    }

    System.out.println("DONE");
```

Comment: On double enter, at least one line is `""`; so you split it by `" "` which yields an array of `{ "" }` and then you try and print the second element (and there isn't one).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ahh yes I see your point, but isn't it supposed to NOT enter the body of the loop from the first place? I mean the line will be equal to NULL won't it?

Comment: `null` is not `""`. You could add `if (line.isEmpty()) break;` before your `split`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ok I get it now. But when will the read line be equal to NULL?

Comment: After someone closes `System.in`; ctrl-z in Windows or ctrl-d everywhere else. That usage is more common with a `File` (which has a more firm "end").

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks Elliott! That really helped.